# R doesn't upload Date

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a Date and after I upload the file the Date transforms into NA. How Can I solve it? I read on the internet that the solution can be readexcel2 but I can't use it. In Excel the date is 20-08-2022

```
multiplesheets <- function(fname) {
  
  # getting info about all excel sheets
  sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(fname)
  tibble <- lapply(sheets, function(x) readxl::read_excel(fname, sheet = x))
  data_frame <- lapply(tibble, as.data.frame)
  
  # assigning names to data frames
  names(data_frame) <- sheets
  
  # print data frame
  pr

int(data_frame)
 }

sheets <- multiplesheets("PATH")
a<-sheets$a
b<-sheets$b
```

[image]

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wCORUtpnuM11jwaVThbIVjShV68uVxwf/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117918543829993309637&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: We need more information if possible. How are you reading the file?

Comment: Can you post the spreadsheet (or at least the little bit of the spreadsheet that contains the date in question) somewhere?  Also, you could make your example more minimal, since presumably `readxl::read_excel()` on the  relevant sheet is all you really need ...

Comment: I have shared on google drive